# How to abstract the Entities Data Context in C#

Tags: c#, repository, datacontext, abstraction

In my application I created a DAL with a Repository class. The Repository uses a set of EF classes as **Data Context**.

I would like to create an abstraction in order to be capable of using multiple **Data Context** with the **same repository**. I use the following code to initialize the context (`ProductEntities` is the EF context):

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
     ?type? _productEntitiesContext;

     public productRepository()
     {
         _productEntitiesContext = new ProductEntities();
     }

     public productRepository(?type? productContext)
     {
         _productEntitiesContext = productContext;
     }
}
```

But I do not know the type of `_productEntitiesContext` (and `productContext`). `ProductEntities` inherits from `ObjectContext`.

In order to achieve abstraction I always use interfaces, I do not know whether I can use `ObjectContext` since it is a class.

Anybody knows if my goal is achievable?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
public class ProductRepository<T> : IProductRepository where T: new()
{
     T _productEntitiesContext;

     public productRepository()
     {
         _productEntitiesContext = new T();
     }

     public productRepository(T productContext)
     {
         _productEntitiesContext = productContext;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. With this you define a generic type T. I want to define something like an interface instead, like IProductRepository but for the context.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the issue in hard-coding `ProductEntities` here - `ProductRepository` anyway seems to be products specific implementation.

If you want to inject `ProductEntities` into your repository w/o taking dependencies onto it then you can create a marker interface such as `IProductEntities` and implement that in `ProductEntities`

```
public interface IProductEntities { }

public partial class ProductEntities : IProductEntities { }
```

Remember although `ProductEntities` is a generated class, you can still add code to it because its partial (as a side note if it was not partial then you could have simply inherited from it)

You probably may want to add some methods to `IProductEntities` interface if you are really thinking of switchable data-contexts. Although, I doubt if there would be any need to switch the context and I am unsure as to who will provide alternate implementation.

As such repository pattern is anyway abstracting data-access so don't see any value in abstracting EF context in this way. Tomorrow, if you want to use another OR wrapper (such as NHibernate), you can probably provide another `IProductRepository` implementation that uses other OR mapper.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was also wondering if it was worth to abstract the context. I thought there was an interface already defined, since it is not the case, I'll leave it as it is

Answer (score 1):

If you’re after a further layer of abstract you could consider unit-of-work and IoC, there are many examples on stackoverflow. The examples for linq-to-sql also apply to Entity framework. I've personally implemented this across a few projects using Entity framework. If your interested it's worth reading about unit-of-work and IoC in the below links.

[DataContext, Repositories and Unit of Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768769/datacontext-repositories-and-unit-of-work)

http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2011/08/18/unit-testing-a-wcf-ria-domainservice-part-2-the-repository-pattern.aspx

hopefully this helps.